# I failed at trying to make a random song player

Tags: java, swing, button, audio, switch-statement

I tried to create a system where you click the button, and it plays a random midi file out of five possible. It always just plays the first song please help. The integer `i` is getting randomly selected, but the URL will not change from `sus2` for a reason that I do not know, thus the audio is staying the same.

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class Option extends JFrame implements ActionListener{   


/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
URL image= this.getClass().getResource("/tick.png");
URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/sus.mid");
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(image);
JButton testBut = new JButton(img);
JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
java.applet.AudioClip audio = JApplet.newAudioClip(url);

public Option(){
    super("Swing Window");

    pnl.add(testBut);
    add(pnl);
    setSize( 500,350);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    testBut.addActionListener(this);




}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

    if (event.getSource() == testBut) {
        int i = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5);
        switch(i){
        case 1: url = this.getClass().getResource("/sus.mid");
        case 2: url = this.getClass().getResource("/sus2.mid");
        case 3: url = this.getClass().getResource("/sus3.mid");
        case 4: url = this.getClass().getResource("/sus4.mid");
        case 5: url = this.getClass().getResource("/sus5.mid");

        System.out.println(i);
        }
        audio = JApplet.newAudioClip(url);
        audio.stop();
        audio.play();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
Option gui = new Option();

}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the break instruction after each of your case block:

```
case 1: 
    url = this.getClass().getResource("/sus.mid");
    break;

case 2: 
    url = this.getClass().getResource("/sus2.mid");
    break;
...
```

Comment: That's the bug. Also, i suggest you get rid of the switch completely. Something like:             this.getClass().getResource("/sus" + i + ".mid");